# uncover box within an equation in beamer

Tags: beamer, boxes, uncover

I have the equation $X+Y=Z$ in one of myslide, and I want a box to appear around $X+Y$ on a mouse click. I know I can use $\boxed{X+Y}=Z$, but then I can separate the box appearance from the $X+Y$ appearance using \onslide.
Is there a solution for this?

Comment: Please always include a [short, but compilable test file](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) in your questions.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `hf-tikz` package:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[beamer]{hf-tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \[
    \tikzmarkin<2->{a}X+Y\tikzmarkend{a}=Z
  \]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]